# How to export / feature the "picture guidelines" field

Tags: 7, users, features

I have some legal mentions to put under the file upload form of user account.

I would like to put them a feature some elements about user configuration, but I'm not able to find which variable (i.e. Strongarm or anything else) is mapped to field "Picture guidelines" 
(available in Home » Administration » Configuration » People).

Could someone give me a hint, or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Strongarm to export the variable called `user_picture_guidelines`.

Comment: Ah ! Indeed I've already exported it ... and so it was not available to export in feature GUI. Thanks :)